# Push to clients using Metadata (Assignments By App, Record Type, and Profile)

Tags: lightning-apps, metadata-api, profile, metadata, flexipages

I'm trying to update Lightning Record Pages with Profiles (**Assignments By App, Record Type, and Profile**):

To get (retrieve) all the details I'm using the following package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>Application_Name</members>
    <name>CustomApplication</name>
  </types>
  <version>42.0</version>
</Package>
```

It returns a .app file with actionOverrides, profileActionOverrides & few other details.

**But the file doesn't contain the namespaces prepended, how can I make it happen? like the pageOrSobjectType, recordType, content come with the prepended namespace.**

**Also, if I want to extract only profileActionOverrides, how can I do that?**

Say I want to deploy only one ProfileActionOverrides - for a particular profile of CustomObject with RecordType1,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

  <formFactors>Large</formFactors>
  <label>Learn</label>
  <navType>Standard</navType>
  <profileActionOverrides>
    <actionName>View</actionName>
    <content>namespace__Custom_Object_RecordType1</content>
    <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
    <pageOrSobjectType>namespace__Custom_Object__c</pageOrSobjectType>
    <recordType>namespace__Custom_Object__c.namespace__RecordType1</recordType>
    <type>Flexipage</type>
    <profile>Standard</profile>
  </profileActionOverrides>

  <uiType>Lightning</uiType>

</CustomApplication>
```

I've manually added the namespace__. I'm successfully able to Deploy to this to any org provided I've the username & password.

But **how can I deploy to a client system without asking for their email & password, also can we do this from Apex side? What are the best ways to deploy to different clients?**

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean here -- [how can I deploy to a client system without asking for their email & password], is [client = sandbox] and [email & password = username & password]?

Comment: client = users who has installed our application/product in their org

Comment: And are you distributing your app as a managed or unmanaged package?

Comment: managed package